# How do you center text on the Moto 360 with respect to the perimeter and not the chin at the bottom? (320dp x 320dp) vs (320dp x 290dp)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, wear-os, moto-360

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=naf_WbtFAlY) video Google mentions using `windowOverscan` in the `styles` file. The problem is I do not have a styles file in my Android Wear module. Is there a more recent method that allows you to center text properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out through experimenting that the `windowOverscan` attribute is set within the style you choose in your `AndroidManifest` file. I was able to view the settings of each style by going to the `Design` tab in the layout xml then finding the `style` attribute and clicking the three dots and then going to the `System` tab. When a style is selected you can see the code at the bottom of the window.

I also [read](https://books.google.com/books?id=OOkmCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA146&lpg=PA146&dq=windows%20Overscan%20android%20developer%20android%20wear&source=bl&ots=USbU8dFX-l&sig=N8jXDqU0UrfTuh3DuiEXIku0IF0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SqNXVfvzG4WxyATjsICgBA&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=windows%20Overscan%20android%20developer%20android%20wear&f=false) that `windowOverscan` is set to `true` by default.

My problem was actually caused by the custom font I was using and not `windowOverscan`. Hope this saves someone the trouble.